# Visual Studio Team Services, 403 forbidden, you do not have licensing rights to access this feature, Overnight lost majority of rights?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Last night a bunch of windows updates occurred to my work pc.

Now when I login to Visual Studio Team Services and attempt to access code or really anything I receive this error.

403 forbidden.

TF400409: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Administer account

We use the free Visual Studio Team Services and only have four users.  Other users can still navigate into the account and view code and user settings.  I am still present as a user and am able to login but have access to only two tabs (Overview and Load Test).

I noticed that my msdn license had lapsed earlier this month, but I am unsure if this is the issue.

Hoping someone else has run into this issue as I can't get to my code.

I have entered a ticket with Microsoft and will post my findings here if they are able to fix my account.

Comment: but Microsoft promised 5 free users https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-pricing-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply back from Microsoft.

[Visual Studio Team Services Membership Descriptions](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/work-as-a-stakeholder-vs.aspx)

Basically, you need at the very least a basic membership to perform admin functions or an MSDN subscription.

I had always had this subscription so I had never seen this issue before.

Long story short, if you use this and your subscription runs dry good luck getting to your code.

(although Microsoft support was very helpful in determining the issue)

Comment: So... You stop paying for a feature, and then complain when the vendor takes your access away? Not sure I sympathize in any way. You can always get one of your paying collogues to give you code, or purchase a one month membership.

Comment: Actually, it is kind of funny as this is another entities source repository that I have taken over.  This entire time I have had msdn subscription when managing their repository.  When it lapsed it revokes essentially all privileges.  The above was an attempt to document this issue and not at all a cry for online sympathy, and none of my colleagues are paying either...

Comment: You need to change the licence in the Users tab on your account to "basic" and not "MSDN".